# Javascript event listener returns null

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new with JavaScript and I am trying to build a simple script that will show in console log the number of characters entered to a text area.

Here is my html:

```
<section class="hero is-info">
<div class="hero-body">
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="search" placeholder="" /><span class="icon is-medium is-left"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><span class="icon is-medium is-right"><i class="fa fa-empire"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my js:

```
const testArea = document.querySelector("#card-content");

function openDropDown(){
let textEnteredLength = testArea.value.length;
console.log(textEnteredLength);
}

testArea.addEventListener("keypress", openDropDown, false);
```

and here is my error:

> TypeError: testArea is null[Learn More]

I don't understand why `testArea` appears to be nulls since I defined it in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You've to add id `card-content` to `input` tag like this -

```js
const testArea = document.querySelector("#card-content");

function openDropDown() {
  let textEnteredLength = testArea.value.length;
  console.log(textEnteredLength);
}

testArea.addEventListener("keypress", openDropDown, false);
```

```html
<section class="hero is-info">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
              <input id="card-content" class="input is-large" type="search" placeholder="" /><span class="icon is-medium is-left"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><span class="icon is-medium is-right"><i class="fa fa-empire"></i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @akalogiros you can check above code in answer and run it. it is working as expected. (you may have forgotten to update `querySelector` to pass `#card-content` and not `card-content`)

Answer (score 0):

You need an `id` to select the DOM element to add an event listener to.

```html
<section class="hero is-info">
<div class="hero-body">
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" id="card-content" type="search" placeholder="" /><span class="icon is-medium is-left"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><span class="icon is-medium is-right"><i class="fa fa-empire"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
const testArea = document.getElementById("card-content");//selects element with id 'card-content'

function openDropDown(){
let textEnteredLength = testArea.value.length;
console.log(textEnteredLength);
}

testArea.addEventListener("keypress", openDropDown, false);
</script>
```

You can also select the element by its class(es).

```html
<section class="hero is-info">
    <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                        <input class="input is-large"  type="search" placeholder="" /><span class="icon is-medium is-left"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><span class="icon is-medium is-right"><i class="fa fa-empire"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    const testArea = document.querySelector("input.input.is-large");
    //selects first input element with class of input and is-large

    function openDropDown(){
    let textEnteredLength = testArea.value.length;
    console.log(textEnteredLength);
    }

    testArea.addEventListener("keypress", openDropDown, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: i updated the html and js accordingly and issue persist..  `TypeError: testArea is null`

Comment: @akalogiros Would you mind putting your code in a JSFiddle for me?

Comment: @akalogiros The problem is probably that your `script` is running before the DOM is ready. Place your `script` after the DOM elements and it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/8n0Lsxtd/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the attribute `onkeyup` and invoke the function `openDropDown()` and pass `this` as an argument to access the `input` element to check the number of the characters which entered to the input field.

```js
function openDropDown(input){
  console.log(input.value.length) 
}
```

```html
<section class="hero is-info">
<div class="hero-body">
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
                    <input class="input is-large" type="search" placeholder="" onkeyup="openDropDown(this)" /><span class="icon is-medium is-left"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><span class="icon is-medium is-right"><i class="fa fa-empire"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```